# Why doesn't app fetch user data from supabase?

Tags: flutter, supabase

I use `fireauth` and `supabase` database together.

If user missed to fill user information in the process of authentication, I navigate user to screen that supplements missing information in `splash screen`.

So the process like below.

```
   UserProfile? userProfile =
          await ref.read(userProvider.notifier).fetchLoggedUserInfo();

      if (networkConnectivityState.value &&
          (userProfile.userId == "" ||
              userProfile.name == "-" ||
              userProfile.name == "" ||
              userProfile.gender == "" ||
              userProfile.birthYear == "" ||
              userProfile.birthDay == "" ||
              userProfile.subdistrictId == "")) {
        Future.delayed(const Duration(seconds: 1), () {
          Navigator.of(context).pushAndRemoveUntil(
            MaterialPageRoute(
              builder: (_) => SupplementProfileScreen(myProfile: userProfile),
            ),
            (route) => false,
          );
        });
      } else {
        Future.delayed(const Duration(seconds: 1), () {
          Navigator.of(context).pushAndRemoveUntil(
            MaterialPageRoute(
              builder: (_) => const MainNavigationScreen(tab: "일기"),
            ),
            (route) => false,
          );
        });
      }
```

The code to fetch user information from supabase.

```
  Future<Map<String, dynamic>?> fetchLoggedUserInfoDB() async {
    try {
      final userData = await _supabase
          .from("users")
          .select('*, subdistricts(*), contract_communities(*)')
          .eq("userId", user!.uid)
          .single();
      return userData;
    } catch (e) {
      // ignore: avoid_print
      print("fetchLoggedUserInfoDB -> $e");
    }
    return null;
  }
```

And then, I convert user data to UserProfile custom model in view model.

If user data is null, It will throws UserProfile.empty()

```
  Future<UserProfile> fetchLoggedUserInfo() async {
    final userData = await _authRepo.fetchLoggedUserInfoDB();
    if (userData != null) {
      state = AsyncData(UserProfile.fromJson(userData));
      return UserProfile.fromJson(userData);
    } else {
      return UserProfile.empty();
    }
  }
```

When I navigate user in splash screen, I execute above code to get user information.

**await ref.read(userProvider.notifier).fetchLoggedUserInfo()**

But The thing is, sometimes even user, who logged in and has all information, is navigated to SupplementScreen which means that from the first splash screen code, userProfile's any column should be "".

```
(userProfile.userId == "" ||
              userProfile.name == "-" ||
              userProfile.name == "" ||
              userProfile.gender == "" ||
              userProfile.birthYear == "" ||
              userProfile.birthDay == "" ||
              userProfile.subdistrictId == "")
```

Since I double-checked the fact that user has all information from supabase database, I guessed it is due to network issue.

I thought maybe network is not connected, so user information is not fetched from supabase and goes to catch block and returns null.

So I add `networkConnectivityState.value` as well with package `connectivity_plus` and make it navigate user to supplement screen **only when network is connected**.

However still sometimes I check sometimes user is navigated to supplement screen!

Probably `fetchLoggedUserInfoDB` that fetched data from supabase may returns null, and fetchLoggedUserInfo() returns `UserProfile.empty()` which all values are assigned empty string "", so It navigates user to supplement screen.

Since once user fill more information, they successfully stored new information to supabase with userId getting from fireauth, `user!.uid` coming from fireauth may not be null.. I think.

And even it happens sometimes!, not always.
What could be the problem here?

Comment: What error are you getting when that happens?